# Hover function with this>find

Tags: jquery, menu, hover, find, this

I am trying a hover like this;

HTML;
`<!-- Item -->
            <li class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                <a href="#home" class="item">
                    Home
                    <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i>
                </a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu to-center mega-menu">...</ul>
            </li>`

jQuery;

```
$(".dropdown-toggle").find('> a i').hover(function(){
    $(this).find('> ul.dropdown-menu').slideUp({duration: 700, easing: "easeInOutQuart"});
        $(this).find('> ul.dropdown-menu').slideDown({duration: 700, easing: "easeInOutQuart"});        
    }, function () {
    $(this).find('> ul.dropdown-menu').slideUp({duration: 700, easing: "easeInOutQuart"});
});
```

But it's not working when i add .find('') code after the $('.dropdown-toggle'). How can i fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You have no `ul.dropdown-menu` element in your `li i a` DOM element.
`$(this)` in second line starts searching in `li a i` element, which is empty.

**UPDATE:**

You have just added `ul.dropdown-menu` but it is still outside `li a i`. It is in `li` element, so change second line of your script to:

```
$(this).closest('li').find('> ul.dropdown-menu')
```

Comment: There is ul.dropdown-menu items after the "a" tags, just added it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working solution. Hope it helps!

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

$(".dropdown-toggle").find('> a i').hover(function(){
 $("#panel").html($(this).closest("ul").find("> ul.dropdown-menu "));
 $("#panel").slideDown({duration: 700, easing: "easeInOutQuart"});

  }, function(){
   $("#panel").slideUp({duration: 700, easing: "easeInOutQuart"});
  });
});
```

```css
#panel {
  margin: 20px;
  display: none;
  border: 1px solid green;
  width: 100px;
  height:30px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.9/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" media="all" /> 
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.5.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.9/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<ul>
<li class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
  <a href="#home" class="item">Home<i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu to-center mega-menu">
      <li>someText</li>
    </ul>
</li>
</ul>
<div id="panel"></div>
```